# does premain class of javaagent work for Web application deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, profiler, javaagents

i'm learning about javaagent and i created a simple profiler

http://www.javabeat.net/2012/06/introduction-to-java-agents/

I profiled a java application and it works fine. can i use this profiler to profile an web application deployed in tomcat. i tried this setting in CATALINA.bat  "SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:/path-to-profiler/profiler.jar" and started the server but i didn't find the required output.